# Sanitizing input before using appendReplacement with pattern matching

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a problem with `appendReplacement` method. I am processing many sources and it happens that some of them contain named group (eg `${name}`).

Example code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HelloWorld{

     private static final Pattern SOURCE_BLOCK_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("<source>.*?</source>");

     public static void main(String []args){
        String inputText = "<p>something</p> <source> <p> @${xx} </p> </source> <p>something</p>";

        Matcher matcher = SOURCE_BLOCK_PATTERN.matcher(inputText);
        StringBuffer buffStr = new StringBuffer();

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String group = matcher.group();
            group = group.replaceAll("<[/]?p>", "");
            matcher.appendReplacement(buffStr, group);
        }
        matcher.appendTail(buffStr);
        String outputText = buffStr.toString();

     }
}
```

And the result is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No group with name {xx}
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:849)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:17)
```

How should I perform such replacement so there is no error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4531877?focusedCommentId=12006806&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-12006806)

> A dollar sign ($) may be included as a literal in the replacement
>   string by preceding it with a backslash (\$).

So by changing method call to:

```
matcher.appendReplacement(buffStr, group.replace("$","\\$"));
```

I got expected result without breaking anything.